# jquery ui 1.9 beta ui autocomplete references a function response() , but I do not find its implementation (sourcecode available)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, widget

```
 response( someObject );
```

this response function is referenced quite a bit, but I cannot find its implementation. Does someone understand what's going on?

[full sourcecode on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.9.0-beta.1/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js)

[full sourcecode raw](https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/1.9.0-beta.1/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js)

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.9.0-beta.1/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L563

Comment: @Martin you are pointing to the filter function. What I don't get is what response() is doing. I get what filter is doing.

Comment: I skimmed your question, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I followed along with the code correctly, [it is implemented as `_response`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.9.0-beta.1/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L410), which appears to be the jQuery autocomplete entry point for displaying your terms (implemented in `__response`).

[`_response` is passed along as `this._response` to functions like `_search`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.9.0-beta.1/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L402) as a callback .

Comment: aha now I understand how it works - e.g. in simple words, _response() gets passed as a function argument which gets referenced as response within the targeted function. What I don't quite understand is what the advantage is, of having a function defined in options, which gets overwritten by internal functions, whatsoever. E.g. options.source gets actually referenced, options.response never.